# SwiftUI sheet being dismissed when asking for system permission

Tags: ios, swift

I'm displaying a SwiftUI-sheet in the following way:

```
struct SomeButton {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            showSheet.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Settings")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: {}) {
                SomeView()
            }
```

And `SomeView()` is at some point calling a system location permission `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` with `locationManager` being an instance of `CLLocationManager`.

The behavior I would like to achieve is to have the triggered system dialog for the location to appear on the presented sheet.

What actually happens: The sheet is being dismissed and then the system dialog is shown.

Is this expected SwiftUI behavior, or is there a way/workaround to present such a system dialog on a SwiftUI sheet, without the sheet being automatically dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a sample and it's working fine for me, the system dialogue for the location appear over the presented sheet.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import CoreLocation

struct MasterView: View {
    @State private var showModal = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show modal") {
               self.showModal = true
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal, onDismiss: {
            print(self.showModal)
        }) {
           ModalView(message: "This is Modal view")
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    let message: String

    var lc = CLLocationManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text(message)
            Button("Request Location ") {
                lc.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
            Button("Dismiss") {
                self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the information i've provided you're absolutely right. Then ist must be some other detail. Gonna update the question as soon as I know more.